Does the CCPA prevent one-time promotional offers?
Harbor Freight has a 10% back discount on your first purchase in their members program. If I accept that and join. And, I immediately cancel and serve a notice that I wish to have all of my Personal Identifiable Information to be deleted from their system, then by law of the remaining information they retain they can't identify me.
What then prevents someone from signing up under another first-time promotional offer?
Is my understanding of the CCPA correct? Or does it provide some kind of exemption in this case so they company can identify you in perpetuity.

Is that all that they have to go on -- your word -- that you're a first time customer when you sign up? They could never have any additional information without incriminating themselves for having violated the CCPA regulation. My question is mostly about whether or not these types of uses of PII are exempted from the CCPA?

The Right to Delete has various exceptions. See a summary on the Attorney General's website (point D.5.), and the referenced sections in the California Civil Code. These exceptions are full of weasel words like "reasonable", but the relevant point is that the Right to Delete is not as absolute as you think. I would expect that taking up such a "new customer" offer allows them to keep identifying info for a reasonable time, e.g. two years.

There is of course the small matter that if you do sign up for another promotional offer, you're committing fraud.

@NateEldredge That sounds like it invites infinite regress. That would be PII, so you can request that it be deleted. They do so, but retain a record of that request. And so on....

I actually looked it up - they're required to maintain a record of the request, but are forbidden from using it for any other purpose than documenting and monitoring their own compliance. So I guess they can't use it to check your first time customer status.

(And the fact that the record is legally required makes it exempt from deletion, so there's no infinite regress.)

The California Consumer Privacy Act of 2018, s. 1798.105(d) provides the following exceptions from deletion:

A business, or a service provider or contractor acting pursuant to its contract with the business, another service provider, or another contractor, shall not be required to comply with a consumer’s request to delete the consumer’s personal information if it is reasonably necessary for the business, service provider, or contractor to maintain the consumer’s personal information in order to:
(1) Complete the transaction for which the personal information was collected, fulfill the terms of a written warranty or product recall conducted in accordance with federal law, provide a good or service requested by the consumer, or reasonably anticipated by the consumer within the context of a business’ ongoing business relationship with the consumer, or otherwise perform a contract between the business and the consumer.
(2) Help to ensure security and integrity to the extent the use of the consumer’s personal information is reasonably necessary and proportionate for those purposes.
(3) Debug to identify and repair errors that impair existing intended functionality.
(4) Exercise free speech, ensure the right of another consumer to exercise that consumer’s right of free speech, or exercise another right provided for by law.
(5) Comply with the California Electronic Communications Privacy Act pursuant to Chapter 3.6 (commencing with Section 1546) of Title 12 of Part 2 of the Penal Code.
(6) Engage in public or peer-reviewed scientific, historical, or statistical research that conforms or adheres to all other applicable ethics and privacy laws, when the business’ deletion of the information is likely to render impossible or seriously impair the ability to complete such research, if the consumer has provided informed consent.
(7) To enable solely internal uses that are reasonably aligned with the expectations of the consumer based on the consumer’s relationship with the business and compatible with the context in which the consumer provided the information.
(8) Comply with a legal obligation.

I have not reviewed the case law, but retaining minimal customer information sufficient to and only for the purposes of identifying non-first-time purchasers may fall under exceptions (2) and (7).

Great find! thanks Jen.
